# PHP: Running if and else if inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run `if` and `else if` inside a while loop in my PHP code.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        $deviceType = $row["deviceType"];

        if($deviceType == 'iPhone' || $deviceType == 'iPad'){
            echo 'IOS';
        }else if($deviceType == 'Android'){
            echo 'Android'; 
        }
    }
} else {
}

?>
```

The code above works (sort of) but not as I was expecting it.

To give you an example, lets say I have 2 rows in MYSQL database.

like this:

```
id     deviceType

1      Android
2      iPhone
```

when i run my PHP code above, I get this echo-ed on my page:

```
IOS
IOS
Android
Android
```

BUT I only have 2 rows in the database so the result should be:

```
IOS
Android
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: if you don't need the ID, change your query to "SELECT deviceType FROM table ORDER BY id"

Comment: No he says he gets duplicates

Comment: @mayersdesign, i do need it. I have one other column which i need and I haven't included in my question.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, correct.

Comment: Are you running the query twice? check it like you ran twice in a loop or something

Comment: I think you need something more like this:
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $product) { $deviceType = $product["deviceType"];

Comment: No, I'm not running twice! that is the strange thing about it.

Comment: @mayersdesign, I was thinking about using foreach but again I thought that might be a bit slow if there is a huge data in the database!

Comment: I still doubt it @DavidHope , have you posted the real code or mock code for better understanding?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I agree. The real code must have something else. That's my guess

Comment: Dump out your variables. Particularly, echo something outside the `if()` block and dump out `$productCount` to help track it down.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, I have obviously changed the code slightly for better understanding in SO but its not that different from the original code.

Comment: Post the original code, You could have missed something.

Comment: @DavidHope are you sure you have two rows? can you share the output of `echo $productCount;`.

Comment: I bet your real SQL query is different and has at leat one JOIN in it. And this JOIN will most likely produce duplicate rows. So share your real SQL statement.

Comment: try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: @Torge, no, i dont have any JOIN in my query. I will post the original code in a bit when i get to my PC.

Comment: @DavidHope did you try `mysql_fetch_assoc` ?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, that's a good one. I'll try that and will post the update here if it worked.

Comment: @DavidHope Your code is working perfectly fine, I just copied and tried to run on my PC and got only 2 results on the PHP output.

Comment: @DavidHope Please share the output of `echo $productCount;`.

Comment: simply add an `print_r($row)` before the if in the while loop. I bet you will see what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This question is clearly misrepresenting your actual code/data.

When your database table has 2 rows, but you are receiving 4 rows then the onus is not on the `fetch`ing function, but on your query or database table data.

If your actual query is as posted in your question, then your table data contains more than two rows.

If your actual query is different from what you posted (say, joining the table with a copy of itself), then your data is fine and your query is failing you.

Regardless of if you are using `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`, `mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)`, or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`, your `while()` loop will only do one iteration for each row of data.

The difference in resultset `fetch`ing functions:

**mysqli_fetch_array($result)**:

```
array(0=>'1', 'id'=>'1', 1=>'Android', 'deviceType'=>'Android')  // 1 row w/ 4 elements
array(0=>'2', 'id'=>'2', 1=>'iPhone', 'deviceType'=>'iPhone')  // 1 row w/ 4 elements
```

**mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)**, or **mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)**:

```
array('id'=>'1', 'deviceType'=>'Android')  // 1 row w/ 2 elements
array('id'=>'2', 'deviceType'=>'iPhone')  // 1 row w/ 2 elements
```

I will rewrite your code and implement some good practices:

```
if($result=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT `deviceType` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`;")){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo ($row["deviceType"]=="Android"?"Android":"IOS");  // inline condition is a personal preference
        }
    }else{
        echo "No rows in `table`.";
    }
}
```

- Only bother declaring a variable if you will use its value more than once (*or if it *dramatically* improves readability to separate it from its single use.)
- So that your variable names are intuitive, name your query variable `$sql` or `$query`; and name your query's result variable `$result`.
- Only `SELECT` columns that you intend to use; `*` is unnecessary for your case.
- Backtick `` ` `` wrapping is not required on column and table names, but doing so will avoid any potential clashes with MySQL keywords.
- Perform a conditional check and declare the `$result` variable as `false` or `[resultset]` in a single step.
- Always check that `$result` is true before calling any functions that access the resultset. (e.g. `mysqli_num_rows()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`).
- `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){` will check for a non-falsey value -- I mean `0` equates to `false` and anything greater than `0` will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be perfectly fine. However, instead of the expected output, you get more items than needed. If I am not mistaken, this means that you have duplicate `deviceType` in your database table. `$productCount` probably has a value of 4. You can get two values if you use this query instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `deviceType` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`
```

but while this should fix the output you get, your data will still hold duplicates, so you might want to look into the data of your table and into the way it was created, find out and fix the problem.

Comment: He says he doesn't have duplicates on table

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam the data given was an example (not necessarily checked real data) and yesterday when I read the comment section, a lot of talk was about the number the query was executed. If the query was executed twice and there was no duplicate, then the result would be alternating values, but we have IOS IOS Android Android instead. In the example data the order of the data was reversed compared to the query result, so we have every reason to assume that he has duplicates.

Comment: @mickmackusa it is up to you, I respect your decision regardless of whether you put the downvote back or not. I really appreciate that you gave a reason and gave me the chance to reflect on it. In many cases downvotes are given without a reason and in those cases I am left with questions, trying to find out what was the problem and in many cases not understanding it. I also try to give a reason each time I downvote a question or answer.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is very simple you are fetching the results twice with the while loop change this line

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

then it will work right, you can see buy the order iPhone iPhone android android that is doing it twice instead of once per loop

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Gert is correct to provide this answer.  An answer should not be provided as a comment for several reasons.  Here are a few: comments that are wrong cannot be downvoted. Comments that are correct can not be selected as an accepted answer.  OP's that receive a satisfactory solution from a comment and then don't return to SO, leave an abandoned question on SO -- and that's is not favorable.  There are probably more reason, if I think a bit more about it, but perhaps have a read of this:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/352329

Comment: @mickmackusa agreed. what do you think about stealing someone's solution?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam It is not necessarily theft.  It _could_ be intellectual convergence.  My position is: never steal/duplicate answers, but creating a unique and correct answer is always okay regardless of what people post as comments.  The way you prevent people "stealing your insights" is to post your answers as answers -- that is how SO is meant to work.

Comment: Yeah agreed :+1:

Comment: This answer is clearly not correct as I explain in my answer.  I must downvote it and I hope that you will remove it from the page to reduce page bloat.